# How many humans have visited Asgard in the comics?

Tags: marvel

In Marvel Cinematic Universe, I know of only one human who has visited Asgard: Jane. What about comics? Is visiting Asgard more frequent in the comics? Have Avengers visited it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Yes, the Avengers have been to Asgard as recently as the "Fear Itself" saga in 2011. They have been there multiple times in their history, usually because of a threat from Asgard such as **[Loki](http://marvel.wikia.com/Loki_Laufeyson_(Earth-616))** or **[the Destroyer](http://marvel.com/universe/Destroyer_%28construct%29)** or **[Karnilla](http://marvel.com/universe/Karnilla)**, or Loki, or **[the Enchantress](http://marvel.com/universe/Enchantress_(Amora))**, or Loki or **[Hela](http://marvel.wikia.com/Hela_(Earth-616))**. Mostly Loki.

[image]

In the previous year's **[Siege](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siege_%28comics%29)** storyline, the leader of HAMMER, Norman Osborne lead an assault on Asgard with his evil Avengers. He was in league with, you guessed it, Loki.

[image]

Comment: To be fair, at the time of *Siege*, wasn't Asgard floating 6 feet above Oklahoma?

Comment: Technically, but it still counts...When I get in from work, I will find the first visit of the Avengers to Asgard. Hard to do research from smartphone.

Comment: That trickster Loki...always up to no good

Comment: Was doing some research and noticed Loki is at the root of 15-20% of the biggest problems in the Marvel Universe. He created the Wrecking Crew, put people on the search for the Evil Eye, schemed with the big dogs Surtur, Karnilla, Amora, used the Destroyer, usurped the throne of Asgard, twice, tried to murder Odin, created the Tri-Sentinel, plotted with the Norman Osborne, had Balder murdered and caused Ragnarok at least once... What does a guy have to do to get executed in Asgard?

Answer (score -1):

The New Mutants [have also been there](http://marvel.wikia.com/New_Mutants_(Earth-616)#Danielle_Moonstar_becomes_a_Valkerie) in issues #79 thru 85, I believe.